# Is it possible to auto-retry firebase cloud-function deploys when doing a full deploy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a large amount of cloud functions (150+) that need to be deployed. When i run the following: `firebase deploy --only functions` to do a full deploy i get the following message:

```
⚠  functions: too many functions are being deployed, cannot poll status.
In a few minutes, you can check status at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/.../functions/logs
You can use the --only flag to deploy only a portion of your functions in the future.

✔  Deploy complete!
```

indicating that the deploy is in progress. The issue i have is that usually several functions fail to deploy due to quota limits or other non-code ralated issues, and these have to be retried/redeployed. When polling firebase will give the code to use to retry these, however, when not polling then no further console output is given. When i access the interface i am able to see which functions failed to deploy:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOinY.png)

Is there an option either in the google interface to retry these, or some command option that can be added to the deploy command to auto-retry failed functions?  Currently i have to manually gather all the failed function-names by manually looking trough the list and run a deploy specifying only those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option to automatically retry.  Maybe you could write code to  scan the logs to figure out what failed and retry yourself.  Alternatively, you could instead [invoke the CLI once for each individual function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions) at a controlled rate, and check the results individually.

What you have here sounds like a feature request, which you could post to the [firebase-tools GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) repo.  You could also reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) to make your needs known.

Comment: Make sense. An auto-retry command flag would make deploy-pipelines much easier too, since there would be more guarantees that the deploy was successful. Currently a full deploy in a pipeline is not safe, since there is no guarantee that everything deployed successfully, and no indication from the console of a partial deploy.